# Compilation failure: error reading JAR file in ~/.m2/repository; invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Tags: java, maven

I'm migrating our Java EE project to use Maven instead of Ant.

For the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javolution</groupId>
      <artifactId>javolution</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I get the following error when trying to compile

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:compile (default-compile) on project JAdaptiv: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\User.IVSTEL1\.m2\repository\javolution\
javolution\5.4.2\javolution-5.4.2.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on
 project JAdaptiv: Compilation failure
error: error reading C:\Users\User.IVSTEL1\.m2\repository\javolution\javoluti
on\5.4.2\javolution-5.4.2.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation fail
ure
error: error reading C:\Users\Croydon.IVSTEL1\.m2\repository\javolution\javoluti
on\5.4.2\javolution-5.4.2.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompiler
Mojo.java:656)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:209)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/deploying-maven-project-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-b/49962580#49962580

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This means that javolution-5.4.2 jar in your local repository is corrupt. I checked the maven repo for the 5.4.2 version on this [link](http://download.java.net/maven/2/javolution/javolution/5.4.2/). You can manually copy the jar from there to your local repository to see if that helps.

You can also try the following steps:-

1. Delete the jar from your local repository `C:\Users\User.IVSTEL1\.m2\repository\javolution\
   javolution\5.4.2\javolution-5.4.2.jar`. Then maven will download it again for you.
2. If the 5.4.2 version still has some issues after re-download then try the following [version](http://javolution.org/).

   `<dependency>
             <groupId>javolution</groupId>
             <artifactId>javolution</artifactId>
             <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: That would work too. In the meantime, I ended up setting up a [maven repository manager](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) which managed to fetch the proper file.

Comment: Yes if have the capability to host nexus or artifactory like repo manager then that's the ideal solution.

Comment: It was sufficient for me to just delete the offending files from my local `.m2/repository` folder, and re-run the Maven build to download them again. Probably, there was either a network glitch downloading the files, or (more likely) the original publisher accidentally uploaded a corrupt file and then corrected their mistake soon after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue while deploying the war on Apache Tomcat 10 + JDK 1.8 (same war worked fine with Tomcat 9+ JDK 1.8), could resolve the issue by changing JDK version to 17 (tomcat 10+ JDK 17)

Answer (score 0):

Steps that I had followed to resolved this issue:

**STEP 1** : Deleted the jar from .m2->repository folder

**STEP 2** : Deleted maven dependencies from Java Build Path->Libraries

**STEP 3** : Right click on Project->Maven->Update Project