# WAR file not starting in tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am failing to start my war file, compiled using maven. When I compile the application without the dependencies added it starts properly but after adding the dependencies I get the following errors. I am using the following development environment windows 7, java SE6, maven 3.0.5.

This is an error generated by tomcat 7

```
Oct 16, 2013 4:56:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processServletContainerInitializers
SEVERE: Failed to process JAR found at URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.4.jar!/] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Oct 16, 2013 4:56:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Oct 16, 2013 4:56:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
WARNING: Failed to process JAR [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.4.jar!/] for TLD files
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
```

The following is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.farchis</groupId>
  <artifactId>F_Quote</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Farchis Estimator</name>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id> 
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Beta4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>     
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
        The JSP/Servlet API libraries are appserver implementation dependent and belongs 
        in case of Tomcat 6 in the Tomcat/lib folder and should in no way be moved
         nor duplicated somewhere else
        bug fix add <scope>provided</scope>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>         
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please check similar problem [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453263/compile-error-in-maven2-invalid-cen-header-bad-signature

Comment: Use Java SE 7. Use primefaces 3.5 or at least 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here problem occurs after you are adding dependencies in your WAR file.So you can remove all these dependencies from `local repository` and regenarate JAR file.

And still you are facing some issues then once try with Tomcat 6.0. Previously I also faced this same issue and I changed my Tomcat and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If still stuck, try with Tomcat 6 once as well!

Comment: is this answer ? you can write the such suggestions in comment. please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: check the comment of  Lutz Horn Its just a small suggestion. not the exact answer of the question.

Comment: That's great :-) It is well known that Tomcat 7 doesn't behave well many times.