# invalid CEN header for wicket 6.15.0 Jar

Tags: maven-2, wicket, wicket-1.6

I am trying to compile a Apache Wicket Project with wicket version 6.15.0.
I am using Apache Wicket 6.15.0 jar, maven dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
   <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
   <version>6.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For this I am getting error as:

```
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\maddy\.m2\repository\org\apache\wicket\wicket-util\6.15.0\wicket-util-6.15.0.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
```

Please guide solution on this.

Comment: You might want to look at the answer to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453263/compile-error-in-maven2-invalid-cen-header-bad-signature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to delete this jar from your maven repository and let maven redownload it again.

> C:\Users\maddy.m2\repository\org\apache\wicket\wicket-util\6.15.0\wicket-util-6.15.0.jar

Comment: Thanks, deleting the wicket-util jar file worked. Maven downloaded the latest jar file and build is success now.